# How/Where to store sensitive information in .netCore project in Azure DevOps/Local

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops

Shortly my scenario is to test a remote API if there was any changes in the called APIs, like some parameter removed or something like that.

To get this info I need to have a token.

My problem is, I can't store it in the Database and use windowsCredentials, because in the AzurePipeline the build agents has no access and connection to the Database. And if I pass the token through variables in the pipeline then I won't have the token when I run the code in local.

appSetting is stored in Git so it is not safe.

Any idea on this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Use a keyvault. Your application can be configured to integrate with the keyvault and pull the values out of it at runtime.

Comment: Create file in project `token.txt` and read it to get the token. The file name must be added in `.gitignore` in order to avoid it being pushed into the git repo

Comment: The build in Azure is automaticly started when new sourcecode is uploaded/modified , If I ignore the token file then it won't be available when it runs there.

Answer (score 0):

UserSecrets + Environment variables are the key here. Appsettings.json is for configuration that is non-sensitive, but there is a concept called user secrets (see link below) that will allow you to have stored an appsettings.json equivalent just on your machine and not in git. When specifying info in it it should override or add onto anything in your appsettings.json.

If that info is also needed for production, then environment variables should be used. Instead of a file, single configurations can be specified/overridden using environment variables.

This is all accomplished ONLY if the aspnet core web server configuration is setup to accept from all of these places. The default setup from the template should accomplish this but read the links below to make sure that your setup works.

All the configuration and best practices can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Non sensitive info/Defaults: appsettings.json

Sensitive info for devs/dev specific info: [UserSecrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=linux)

Sensitive info for prod: Environment variables